# Trying to make sense of MS documentation on AAD development

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm writing an app development guide and I'm struggling with a few things:

First of all there are currently 2 endpoints in AAD (v1 and v2), there are also 2 pathways of registering apps in the AAD portal (app registrations and app registrations preview). I can't seem to find confirmation that usage of the app registrations preview blade enforces usage of the v2 endpoint, can anyone confirm? Our users authenticate using WS-Federation which is currently not supported by the v2 endpoint which is why I want to avoid usage of v2 for now.

I'm also looking for the best method of allowing access to the Graph API through a service account with delegated permissions (for more granular scoping).

Anyone that can clarify?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of application you are planning to build ? Wep API, Native or SPA?

Comment: I'm looking at the on-behalf-of flow on the v1 endpoint which requires 2 applications, an API in front of the Graph API and a client app.

Comment: What kind of operations are you looking to do with the Graph API?

Comment: Preferably anything (CRUD operations mainly), the idea is to define an approach to delegate permissions in Graph through a technical account.

E.g.: a developer can create an app that calls Graph through a service account with no user interaction (deamon) that allows him to manage all AAD/O365 resources where the service account has access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to find confirmation that usage of the app registrations preview blade enforces usage of the v2 endpoint, can anyone confirm?

An app registered in either registration experience can be used with both the v1 and v2 endpoints. Some features can only be configured in the preview experience, though (e.g. support for Microsoft Accounts).

Comment: Thanks Philippe! That's what I expected but wasn't sure. The usage of the authentication library MSAL is not available in the GUI of the non-preview but you can still configure it in the app manifest I assume.

Do you have any pointers concerning the delegated permissions approach?